# My state array is not rendering at component start. I am running a conditional to not get stuck in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, node.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import  { Grid, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, CardActionArea, Box, ButtonGroup, Button } from '@mui/material';
import abilities from "../../gameobjects/abilities";

function CharacterCard({character, actionRelay}) {
    const [roleabilities, setRoleAbilities] = useState([])
    
    if(roleabilities.length === 0){
        const abilitesArray = [];
        abilitesArray.push(abilities[character.role])
        setRoleAbilities(abilitesArray)
        console.log(roleabilities)
    }

    console.log(roleabilities)
    const buttonsArray = roleabilities.map((role, id) => {
        return( 
        <Button
          value={role.name}
          key={id}
          background={'../../images/buttons/slash.png'}
          >
        </Button>)
      })
    function performAction() {

    }
    return(
    <Card style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
                 <h2>{character.name}</h2>
             <Box>
                <ButtonGroup>
                {roleabilities.length > 1 ? buttonsArray : 'Hold up'}
                </ButtonGroup>
             </Box>    
            </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
    )
 }


export default CharacterCard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setRollAbilities` what React does is flag the component as needing a re-render and then, on the next render, uses the new value.

A state variable is something that changes from render to render. You set it's initial value in the useState call, and then can update it when users, for example, click things or whatever. Right now you are setting it's initial value to an empty array, but that doesn't seem to be what you want it's initial value to be.

I've rewritten your useState call so that it is initialized properly to it's actual initial value:

```
const [roleabilities, setRoleAbilities] = useState(
    [abilities[character.role]]
)
```

and then you can get rid of the `if(roleabilities.length === 0)` block of code entirely

---

Note: Really, right now it looks like you might be over-complicating things by making `roleAbilities` a state variable. Since you never use the setState functionality, you don't need it to be state, it can just be a variable. You could for example just write:

```
const roleabilities =  [abilities[character.role]]
```

At present this would give you the same functionality. Unless you are actually gonna use `setRoleAbilities` to change the value, there is no need for it to be a state variable.

Comment: Thanks man. What you said made perfect sense. I think at this point I am just seeing what I can do. IF i can set something as state ill try it out just to see how it works. But you are correct. I think I am trying to make this way too baller instead of just making it dry. Thanks for your help. This worked flawlessly.

Comment: @CharlesRM7792 I totally respect trying things out. I think the key thing is that state variables are variables that change as a result of actions that take place inside the component. If you want to play around with state variables, I'd encourage you to work on adding more interactivity. Perhaps make the component respond to hovering over it, or allow the user to click on certain elements to "select" them and see more information? That kind of functionality could be good for exploring state variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to use the `useEffect` hook to trigger an update to your state when the component renders.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import  { Grid, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, CardActionArea, Box, ButtonGroup, Button } from '@mui/material';
import abilities from "../../gameobjects/abilities";

function CharacterCard({character, actionRelay}) {
    const [roleabilities, setRoleAbilities] = useState([])
    
  useEffect(() => {
   setRoleAbilities(abilities[character.role])
  }, [])

    console.log(roleabilities)
    const buttonsArray = roleabilities.map((role, id) => {
        return( 
        <Button
          value={role.name}
          key={id}
          background={'../../images/buttons/slash.png'}
          >
        </Button>)
      })
    function performAction() {

    }
    return(
    <Card style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
                 <h2>{character.name}</h2>
             <Box>
                <ButtonGroup>
                {roleabilities.length > 1 ? buttonsArray : 'Hold up'}
                </ButtonGroup>
             </Box>    
            </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
    )
 }
```